# Find the first nonblank cell in array and write on it

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet with 10 columns:

```
A Client#

B Date_appointment_1

C Hour_arrival_1

D Hour_departure_1

E Date_appointment_2

F Hour_arrival_2

G Hour_departure_2

H Date_appointment_2

I Hour_arrival_2

J Hour_departure_2.
```

I have also created a data entry form featuring 4 fields:

```
Client#

Date of appointment

Hour of arrival

Hour of departure
```

and a button named "Record data". When pressing that button, I want to locate the row corresponding to that particular client and write the date and hours in the first blank cells. After that, I want the form to accept new data. For instance, I have client# 12345 in A55. B55, C55 and D55 are not blank. When pressing the button, I want the macro to write in E55, F55 and G55.
I did a lot of research but the only thing I can find is how to locate the first non blank cell, not how to write in the next available one.

I am now very good in VBA and I'm trying to learn. I appreciate your help.

Comment: do a little research on `offset`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.